# How to keep order after extracting a subset of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I  want to make a dictionary (or list) that is a subset of another dictionary. Please look at my code below:

```
ThePythons = {
    'GC': 'Graham Chapman',
    'JC': 'John Cleese',
    'EI': 'Eric Idle',
    'MP': 'Michael Palin'
}

query = ['EI', 'JC']

output = {key: value for key, value in ThePythons.items() if key in query}
print(output)
```

Sometimes the output is:

```
{'JC': 'John Cleese', 'EI': 'Eric Idle'}
```

and sometimes is:

```
{'EI': 'Eric Idle', 'JC': 'John Cleese'}
```

How to keep (save) the output in exactly the same order as query is? I want the output **always** as:

```
{'EI': 'Eric Idle', 'JC': 'John Cleese'}
```

The output can also be a list type (`<class 'list'>`). For example:

```
[['EI', 'Eric Idle'], ['JC', 'John Cleese']]
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered in Python.

Comment: In python 3.7+ dictionaries are ordered based on order of insertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over list and get item from dictionary using list comprehension:

```
output = [[item,ThePythons[item]] for item in query if item in ThePythons]
print output
```

output:

```
[['EI', 'Eric Idle'], ['JC', 'John Cleese']]
```

Using map:

```
map(lambda x: [x,ThePythons[x]] if x in ThePythons else [x,"Not found"], query)
```

Comment: It work as I expected. Thank you! BTW, your example with the map function is awesome! However, I will choose the first because _Simple is better than complex_ ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are unordered.  You have to use a list comprehension instead of a dictionary comprehension to keep the order:

```
output = [(key, ThePythons[key]) for key in query]
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I chose the @user3's solution, because his solution is little better. (I'm sorry, I can accept only one answer as accepted answer)

Comment: This answer is valid for Python <=3.6, since 3.7+, dicts maintain insertion order, see https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.7+, your code keeps order:

```py
ThePythons = {
    'GC': 'Graham Chapman',
    'JC': 'John Cleese',
    'EI': 'Eric Idle',
    'MP': 'Michael Palin'
}

query = ['EI', 'JC']

output = {key: value for key, value in ThePythons.items() if key in query}
print(output)
```

always returns

```
{'EI': 'Eric Idle', 'JC': 'John Cleese'}
```